# Event handler for text flow direction change

Tags: c#, wpf

I searched a lot but didn't find anything. Is there any event for `TextBox` in WPF which fires whenever text direction is changed?

Comment: May I know your actual requirement and why you need that event??

Comment: @Sivasubramanian I want to notify user to change the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there is no event for text direction changed, however maybe you can use `TextChanged` or `DataContextChanged`

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx) are all events for the `textbox`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm little bit confused.if you change the TextBox.TextAlign Property then only the direction will be change .

> whenever text direction is changed?

user only defined that direction ..

So,my point try " *TextBox.TextAlignChanged Event* " .if textbox direction is changed , the event is will raise

Comment: anyway thanks, but I meant the 'FlowDirection' property to be changed.